# Python Selenium scrape data when button "Load More" doesnt change URL

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using the following code to attempt to keep clicking a "Load More" button until all page results are shown on the website:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def startWebDriver():
    global driver
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
    
startWebDriver()
driver.get("https://together.bunq.com/all")
time.sleep(4)

while True: 
    try: 
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10,10)
        element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[title='Load More']")))
        element.click()
        print("Loading more page results")
    except: 
        print("All page results displayed")
        break;
```

However, since the button click does not change the URL, no new data is loaded into chromedriver and the while loop will break on the second iteration.

Comment: Please post your full code, can't reproduce the issue with just this

Comment: I updated with the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium is overkill for this. You only need `requests`. Logging one's network traffic reveals that at some point JavaScript makes an XHR HTTP GET request to a REST API endpoint, the response of which is JSON and contains all the information you're likely to want to scrape.

One of the query-string parameters for that endpoint URL is `page[offset]`, which is used to offset the query results for pagination (in this case the "load more button"). A value of `0` corresponds to no offset, or "start at the beginning". Increment this value to suit your needs - in a loop would probably be a good place to do this.

Simply imitate that XHR HTTP GET request - copy the API endpoint URL and query-string parameters and request headers, then parse the JSON response:

```
def get_discussions():

    import requests

    url = "https://together.bunq.com/api/discussions"

    params = {
        "include": "user,lastPostedUser,tags,firstPost",
        "page[offset]": 0
    }

    headers = {
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }

    response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()

    yield from response.json()["data"]


def main():
    for discussion in get_discussions():
        print(discussion["attributes"]["title"])
    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
⚡️What’s new in App Update 18.8.0
Local Currencies Accounts Fees
Local Currencies 
Spanish IBANs Service Coverage 
bunq Update 18 FAQ 
Phishing and Spoofing - The new ways of scamming, explained 
Easily rent a car with your bunq credit card 
Giveaway - Hallo Deutschland! 
Giveaway - Hello Germany! 
True Name: Feedback 
True Name 
What plans are available?
Everything about refunds 
Identity verification explained! 
When will I receive my payment?
Together Community Guidelines      
What is my Tax Identification Number (TIN)?
How do I export a bank statement? 
How do I change my contact info?
Large cash withdrael
```

If this is a new concept for you, I would suggest you look up tutorials on how to use your browser's developer tools (Google Chrome's Devtools, for example), how to log your browser's network traffic, REST APIs, HTTP, etc.

Comment: Thank you. However, I would subsequently actually like to click on each of the posts and retrieve the entire information contained which is not possible using the JSON as it does not provide the URL to the complete discussion for each of the posts

Comment: @FabianKraus The URL can be constructed via `"https://together.bunq.com/d/{}-{}".format(discussion["id"], discussion["attributes"]["slug"])`.